# How style beaches on Google Maps using the Javascript Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to style a Google Map using the JavaScript API (v3). However, I am hitting what seems to be an undocumented feature type.

In a standard Google Map, the beach appears a nice sandy colour.  However, there is no feature type than I can deduce for the beach itself.  I can style *landscape* or *landscape.natural* but that will style the beach and other features as well.  Neither the documented, *landscape.natural.landcover* or *landscape.natural.terrain* target this.

I am following the documented features here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference

Here is an example map with a beach:
https://goo.gl/maps/dgwoPcVTX9M2

Here is some sample code:

```
function initMap() { // My init map function
    var location = {lat: 54.620231, lng: -1.077282};

    var mapStyles = [{
        featureType: 'landscape.natural',
        elementType: 'geometry.fill',
        stylers: [{color: '#00ff00'}]
    }];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('google-map'), 
        {
            styles: mapStyles,
            zoom:15
        }
    );
}
```

This is just a sample code-piece that makes *landscape.natural.terrain*, bright green.  It will turn both the beach and the 'natural terrain near the beach green.  I cannot find a documented feature-type to target just the beach.

Does anyone know how to target this? I find it surprising that an obvious feature like this cannot be styled. The API has been live for years and beaches appeared sandy-coloured for as long as I can remember in Google Maps. Hence, I assume there is an obvious way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: The reference is the reference. You don't have a feature type for every possible thing. I see 2 "solutions"... 1) If you need this for some beaches only, get their geometry and overlay a colored polygon on top and 2) Create a new [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188853) in the hope that Google will add that feature type... one day... maybe.

Comment: Fair enough done that: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/123485214